# How to create a Biometrics based authentication in a Java EE application .?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, biometrics

I creating a web application in Java EE platform. I want to create a log in page in JSP that authenticate user using Biometric Face recognition . Then the Face image is authenticated by the server.(Face recognition  based authentication ).

Please tell me how to implement a Face Recognition  authentication in my Jsp login page.

Also tell for all bio-metrics devices.

Note: I am using WebSphere Application Server and RAD for my development. So the implementation must fully support both.

Comment: What device do you want to use? [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 3):

IMO this is a very strange security requirement and I don't think you will find some kind of hands on tutorial for this by Googling.
The most strict authentication based mechanism I know of is using `CAC` cards that have personal certificate of employees and the login is restricted according to client certificate authentication.
This is also straightforward for session expiration etc.
Even if you were able to implement a face recognition scheme, how would you handle security when session expires browser closes etc?
Keep scanning images and send them to server? The performance would be horrible and I have no idea if it offers any real/extra security than the norm of using smart cards(certificate based authentication).
If you have such strong security requirements, what I would suggest is for your company to hire a security consultant for guidance in your project.